# pivot layout like windows navigation menus using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need code for tabbar with scroll bar like below image, once navigate the menu corresponding screen will show, please suggest any sample or code,

[sample image please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TorHe.png)

Comment: im trying here, can any one please give the solution

https://jsfiddle.net/gjvnrevb/2/

Comment: exactly like this https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Pivot/Overview/jQuery/iOS/

Answer (score -1):

Exactly what you are looking for: [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/tabs.html).

Comment: im trying here , with out any framework but still im struck , can you look at this
https://jsfiddle.net/gjvnrevb/2/